# Integration testing in python, suggested tools and practices?

Tags: python, integration-testing

I've some hard time understanding Integration testing in general, I want to do some integration testing in python expecially for network programming in twisted (but I want to know something more in general).

There are any good resource I must read, and tools (python tools if possible), practices that introduces me in integration testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recent Pycon had *many* talks on testing. All of the videos are available on Vimeo and the slides can be downloaded.: http://us.pycon.org/2010/conference/talks/?filter=testing

Specifically, I recommend the talk by [Ned Batchelder](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-tests-and-testability-188-3280697). The other ones are probably good too. (altho' I haven't seen them)

Comment: I found the ned batchelder talk really useful for my purposes! Thanks!

Comment: I get a not found page with the link.

Comment: up-to-date link instead of dead one is: **http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011** (taken and checked from [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1066315))

Comment: All links are broken :-(

Comment: Ned Batchelder talks currently available here: https://pyvideo.org/speaker/ned-batchelder.html

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer.  Can you add a summary of the contents to reduce the impact of link rot?